# Can I use KitKat app in Jelly Bean?

Tags: android, android-4.2-jelly-bean, android-4.4-kitkat

I am planning to develop an Android app and has been thinking about which version of Android I should choose to develop the app.

I researched a lot of good things about KitKat, but the market occupation of Jelly Bean is still much bigger (13% vs ~60%). If I develop an app in KitKat, can I still use it in Jelly Bean?

Thanks!

Comment: if you set your minSdk to a Jellybean version yes

Comment: Related: you can find market share statistics for clients connecting to Google Play at [Android Developer Dahsboards](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your android project there is an XML file called AndroidManifest.xml. In that file there should be an entry as follows:-

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="16"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

The minSdkVersion setting will allow you to specify that the app requires at least this version of Android to allow its installation. Jelly Bean api levels range from 16 to 18. So if you use the entry above then your app should work on Jelly Bean as well as KitKat. More details about this can be found in the Android Developer documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html).

Answer (score 1):

Yes of course. You can use your app in Jelly Bean too. When you develop your android application you've to set up the min sdk version.